# Use of aggregators in mongo atlas UI

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

I am using aggregate pipeline in mongo atlas, using UI, and I am able to nail down it a bit , however I am not able to do district on particular field.

I have filtered it until below now I want only distinct of ID as a list like how we get in sql.

`select distinct(ID) from table.`

```
orderReceivedBy: “something”
ID: 150435     
country: “UAE”     
createdAt: 2022-02-14T09:55:59.393+00:00

orderReceivedBy: “something”
ID: 150435     
country: “IN”     
createdAt: 2022-02-14T09:55:59.393+00:00

orderReceivedBy: “something”
ID: 150435     
country: “NL”     
createdAt: 2022-02-14T09:55:59.393+00:00
```

Result should be

```
UAE
IN
NL
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can get the unique countries in an aggregation pipeline is by using a `"$group"` stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "countries": {
        "$addToSet": "$country"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "countries": [
      "UAE",
      "NL",
      "IN"
    ]
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NOnAsH-dkwu).